# Looking for simple gradle project for Karate automation

Tags: testing, automation, karate

I am looking for a sample/example gradle project for karate automation. Tried in karate-demo but it didn't helps.
Simple skeleton will also helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this wiki page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Gradle

> ```
> plugins {
>     id 'java'
> }
>
> ext {
>     karateVersion = '0.9.5.RC4'
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     testCompile "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:${karateVersion}"
>     testCompile "com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:${karateVersion}"
> }
>
> sourceSets {
>     test {
>         resources {
>             srcDir file('src/test/java')
>             exclude '**/*.java'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> test {
>     useJUnitPlatform()
>     systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
>     systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
>     outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
> }
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }
> ```

Comment: @Peter Thomas, Can you help me in understanding when we can expect the RC version to be released, or can we use this RC4 version in our production

Comment: @TikTik I can confirm that you can use RC4 in prod for API testing - the wait is for some of the UI automation capabilities

Answer (score 1):

I use VSCode, but with that said, here's my generic Karate tester project build.gradle:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult.ResultType

plugins {
    id "java"
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def karateVersion = "0.9.6"
    
    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:$karateVersion"
    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:$karateVersion"
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file("src/test/java")
            exclude "**/*.java"
        }
    }
}

test {
    testLogging {
        events  TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showCauses true
        showExceptions true
        showStackTraces true
        outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
        showStandardStreams true
    }
    
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
}

task karateExecute(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.intuit.karate.cli.Main"
}
```