# How to run Karate DSL Runner.java in Gradle project?

Tags: gradle, parallel-processing, karate

We were enjoying life with Karate DSL Maven project until now. A decision from management and Developers to move to Gradle made it harder.

How can I execute DemoTestParallel.java with selectable features under classpath?

My connecting question will be, what about parallel execution like in Maven?

FYI, I already configured gradle.build. So my question is not similar to the one at "[Looking for simple gradle project for Karate automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837152/looking-for-simple-gradle-project-for-karate-automation)". But my ask is to execute runner with more controls in gradle.

```
    public class DemoTestParallel {
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {        
        TestBase.beforeClass();
    } 
    
    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        System.setProperty("karate.env", "demo"); // ensure reset if other tests (e.g. mock) had set env in CI
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:demo").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);        
    }
    
    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {        
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: there should be no change to your JUnit code. please refer the links, there's plenty of docs

Comment: @PeterThomas, sorry that it did not help. Usually, in Maven/Junit/Karate way, I get an option to directly run the xxxRunner.java from a right click. 
This is not available in gradle. Also, as we dont have any main method, we can not use a run from jar like other java projects.  like.. 

task runFinalJar(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath = files('build/libs/foo.jar')
   classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   main = full.package.classname
}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic build.gradle that I use:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestResult.ResultType

plugins {
    id "java"
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def karateVersion = "0.9.6"
    
    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:$karateVersion"
    testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:$karateVersion"
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file("src/test/java")
            exclude "**/*.java"
        }
    }
}

test {
    testLogging {
        events  TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT
        exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showCauses true
        showExceptions true
        showStackTraces true
        outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
        showStandardStreams true
    }
    
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
}

task karateExecute(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.intuit.karate.cli.Main"
}
```

My project is just a standard gradle project otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also help while configuring gradlew ? Also, How how should my task or test be configured, if my folder structure has many sub directories per application?

Comment: Can anyone help with configuring Task or Test in build.gradle ?

Comment: Those questions cover core gradle features, you should read the gradle documentation and ask again in the gradle area of stackoverflow if you still have questions.